# Append Changeset to Associated Changesets in TFS Build

Tags: tfs, build-process

I have a custom TFS build template that performs a checkout and checking of a file during the build. I've added additional steps (using the activity equivalent for the code below) to the build template in order to get the changeset that is generated.

```
TFS=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(My_Team_Project_URI)
TFSService=TFS.GetService(of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer)()
LatestChangeset=TfsService.GetChangeset(LatestChangesetNumber)
```

**Note:** The LatestChangesetNumber is found using other methods.

However, I cannot seem to associate the changeset to the build itself. I've tried using the AddToCollection activity and re-associating the changesets to the build using the AssociateChangeSetsAndWorkItems activity.

But for whatever reason the build does not include the last changeset in the associated changesets. Any ideas?

Comment: AssociateChangeSets activity will only get the original changeset. What's the purpose  when you get the latest changeset? Did you want to trigger the build for the lateset changeset?

Comment: The build is running on a daily schedule and since a change is made to the solution during the scheduled build, this triggers the build to be run the next day. By getting the changeset made by the build process and appending it to the associated changesets, I hope to break the loop that is created.